# Show that a homogeneous markov-chain is still a markov-chain after replacing the index with a monotonic increasing sequence.

Tags: markov-chains

Let $X = (X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$
be a homogeneous Markov-chain and $(n_r)_{r \in \mathbb{N}_0}$
a monotonic increasing sequence in $\mathbb{N}_0$.
How can I show that $$Y = (Y_r)_{r \in \mathbb{N}_0} = (X_{n_r})_{r \in \mathbb{N}_0}$$ is as well a Markov-chain?

I could argue that the multiplication of the transition matrix is still a transition matrix, but this doesn't seem clean enough. I think you could 
also somehow prove this by induction, but I am unsure of the induction step as this is my first Markov-chain homework.

Comment: it is only true if $n_r$ is an *arithmetic* sequence

Comment: Does your definition of *Markov chain* allow for time-inhomogeneity?

Comment: @kimchilover No. I edited the question

Comment: I think mercio is correct in the sense that only if $(n_r)$ is an arithmetic sequence is $Y$ is a homogeneous Markov chain whenever $X$ is a homogeneous Markov chain. But if $X$ is an i.i.d. sequence then $Y$ is a homogeneous Markov chain for all subsequences  $(n_r)$.

Comment: Could you provide me with a counter example? Nothing comes to my mind

Comment: @hekri, counter example to what?  If you take "Markov chain" to mean possibly inhomogeneous Markov chain, then the answer to your original question is always "yes".  Your intuition that products of transition matrices are transition matrices is of course correct; in the inhomogeneous case the number of matrices you are multiplying varies, and the products work out differently.  Just for info, what is your precise definition of Markov chain?

Comment: Counter example to my question i.e. an example for a monotonic increasing sequence that doesn't yield a homogenous markov chain. I use the following definition/property of homogenous markov chains $\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = y \vert ( X_n, X_{n-1}, \dots, X_0) = (x, x_{n-1}, \dots,x_0)) = \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = y \vert  X_n = x) = \mathbb{P}(X_{1} = y \vert  X_0 = x)$

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be found in Grimmett, Stirzaker *Probability and Random Processes*, p. 219, 3rd edition.

For any sequence $i_0$, $i_1$, ... of states, consider

\begin{align}
P(Y_{k+1}=i_{k+1} | Y_r=i_r \text{ for } 0\leq r \leq k)&=\frac{P(X_{n_s}=i_s \text{ for } 0 \leq s\leq k+1)}{P(X_{n_s}=i_s \text{ for }0\leq s \leq k)} \\ & \overset{(*)}=\frac{\prod \limits_{s=0}^{k}p_{i_s,i_{s+1}}(n_{s+1}-n_s)}{\prod \limits_{s=0}^{k-1}p_{i_s,i_{s+1}}(n_{s+1}-n_s)} \\ &=p_{i_k,i_{k+1}}(n_{k+1}-n_k)=P(Y_{k+1}=i_{k+1} | Y_k=i_k).
\end{align}

Here $(*)$, we use that it the sequence is increasing.